# Vim delete visual selection and switch to insert mode

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I often find myself doing a visual selection, then hitting <kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>x</kbd> to delete and switching to Insert mode with <kbd>i</kbd>.

Is there a single keystroke that will delete the current visual selection and put me in Insert  mode?

Comment: You should try vimtutor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `c` or `s` to **change** the text and remain in insert mode

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear answer. I noticed that `s` will also work in visual mode, without a selection made (single character delete and start insert) which is handy.

Comment: C for caret, S for substitute?

Answer (score 7):

I think you just want to press <kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: **+1** for the effort to avoid the warning of the 30 characters limit :-)

Comment: Hah! Thanks, glad someone noticed.

Answer (score 3):

The vim help just answers your question exactly:

```
{Visual}["x]c   or                  *v_c* *v_s*
{Visual}["x]s       Delete the highlighted text [into register x] and
            start insert (for {Visual} see |Visual-mode|).  {not
            in Vi}

                            *v_r*
{Visual}["x]r{char} Replace all selected characters by {char}.

                            *v_C*
{Visual}["x]C       Delete the highlighted lines [into register x] and
            start insert.  In Visual block mode it works
            differently |v_b_C|.  {not in Vi}
                            *v_S*
{Visual}["x]S       Delete the highlighted lines [into register x] and
            start insert (for {Visual} see |Visual-mode|).  {not
            in Vi}
                            *v_R*
{Visual}["x]R       Currently just like {Visual}["x]S.  In a next version
            it might work differently. {not in Vi}
```

I would remind the `surround plugin` users, with its default mapping, it overwrites the `{visual}S`.