# VIM Nerdcommenter (<leader>c<space> does not toggle comments

Tags: vim

When I visually select text then hit c, my text is removed and I am put into insert mode, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305556/vim-delete-visual-selection-and-switch-to-insert-mode).

Comment: Do any (normal mode, other visual mode) NERDCommenter mappings work, or does it appear that the plugin isn't installed at all? Do you see the NERDCommenter mappings with `:verbose xmap <Leader>c`?

Comment: When you hit `c` or when you hit `<leader>c`?

Comment: @Ingo Karkat<leader>c

Comment: Are you sure that you installed it correctly and success? Can you see the help docs with `:help nerdcommenter`?

Comment: @wlisrausr Yes,  that works fine. I wonder if there is something in my .vimrc that would cause this, but I checked that also in the past day or so and saw nothing. I am puzzled

Comment: @IngoKarkat Sorry I missed your comment; when  I try `:verbose xmap <Leader>c` I see 10 lines of nerdcommenter "Last set from...." displayed.

Comment: Solved it.. I put `let mapleader = '\'` at the top of my vimrc, after looking up "vim leader doesn't work"

Comment: Cool. So you just need to change the vim leader key to make it works.

Comment: Alright, so something changed your `mapleader`, and you had to restore it to its default. Please either delete your question, or write and answer yourself (if you think this could help others with the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem apparently has to do with the way vim loads plugins, as I understand from googling "Vim Leader doesn't work".

[Stackexchange link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189055/vim-and-gvim-leader-key-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I put a line in the top of my vimrc `let map leader = '\'` (or anything you want), and all is well now.